# Build Succeeds Locally | Succeeds & Fails at CodeBuild AWS | Build Logs Shows App Up and Running | Status In Progress Forever

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a django app that runs fine locally, when I attempt to send it to CodeBuild, the Build logs shows my app running in the console however the build never completes and the status is "in progress"

This is taking from the build logs showing that my build has succeeded:

[image]

But the Status shows in "in progress" however it never installs:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you need more information to assist. Essentially the build logs in AWS CodeBuild and Github Actions shows the app running and listening at http://0.0.0.0:8000 but does not move to the deploy step in AWS CodeBuild. 

On my local machine I see the same output as the AWS CodeBuild log shows, however on my local machine I can go to my browser  at http://localhost:1337/ and view the app deployed.

Comment: I even have the code running nicely in a working manner on a stand alone aws ec2 instance. Any guidance is appreciated it.